# ¿Cómo obtener datos de MongoDB a través de petición get con Nodejs?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

En el archivo /controllers/request.js

```
var RequestsController =  {

getRequests: function(req, res) {
    console.log(req);
    var query = {};
    console.log(req.query);

    Request.find(query, function (err, elements) {

        if (err){
            res.status(500).json({error: false, message: err.message});
        }

        return res.status(200).json(elements);
    });
} 
module.exports = RequestsController;
```

En el archivo que hago la petición de los datos (peticion.js)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Requests = require('../models/request.js');
var RequestsController = require('../controllers/requests.js');
datos = RequestsController.getRequests({"estado": "PENDIENTE", "nombre" : "Juan"});
```

La cuestión es, que quiero hacer una petición get a una de la colecciones de MongoDB, filtrando por ejemplo por los datos "estado" y "nombre".
¿Es correcto lo que estoy haciendo? ya que me devuelve "datos" como undefined... A ver si me podéis echar una mano...

PD. He omitido el archivo con schema del model para no saturar de código pero éste es correcto.

Comment: a ver si te ayuda de algo esto https://stackoverflow.com/a/27995038/3994630

Comment: ¿Y el contenido de `RequestsControllers`? Asumo que el error está allí ya que las consultas en mongo son asíncronas y tú esperas devolver algo como si el código dentro de `getRequests` fuese síncrono.

Comment: El contenido de RequestsControllers es el del código de arriba (archivo controllers/request.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que *getRequests* contiene en su interior una operación asincrónica (Request.find) y por lo tanto,

```
return res.status(200).json(elements);
```

nunca se retorna (ni el error).

Sin embargo, antes preguntas si es el modo correcto en hacerlo. Entonces tu pregunta puede tener dos respuestas: una para decirte

- Cómo reparar el undefined con tu código como lo muestras.
- Mostrar cómo puedes hacerlo mejor.

**Reparar undefined**

Para eso puedes usar un [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) o [promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise)

En los links viene código de ejemplo, asumo que no es necesario escribirte el código aquí y que puedes revisar los links para adaptarlo tú mismo.

**Mostrar cómo hacerlo mejor**

¿Omitiste algún archivo? ya que lo mejor es usar rutas ya sea si usas [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) o node puro.

En el link de express viene un ejemplo de cómo hacer una ruta para una petición, en tu caso sería algo como

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/consulta/:query', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.query) // << puedes hacer tu find() con ese param
  res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Lo principal es que tu undefined es por lo antes dicho, porque estás invocando una función que contiene una operación asincrónica y debes usar callback o promesas. Lo demás puede ayudarte también.

Comment: Muy buena explicación, lo he entendido y resuelto perfectamente, gracias!!